# View percentage value in jqxGauge

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

i am trying to create a gauge using jqxGauge the demo of the gauge is available here http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgauge/index.htm#demos/jqxgauge/defaultfunctionality.htm.

i am not bale to make the gauge accept and display a value like 88.65% or 10.22% or something like that. can someone please tell me how to do it

Comment: can you post your code here ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe a Number value is expected for setting the Gauge's value. It is also possible to format the displayed value, see here: [gauge sample.](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgauge/defaultfunctionality.htm?classic)